# jQuery ScrollTo does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, scrollto

I'm creating a website with horizontal scrolling. I'm using [this](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) jQuery plugin for automatic scrolling. Below is the code.

**HTML**

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="menubutton" id="homeLink"><a class="menuitem" href="#"></a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="menubutton" id="aboutLink"><a class="menuitem" href="#"></a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="menubutton" id="musicLink"><a class="menuitem" href="#"></a></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- end of navigation -->


<div id="firstMark"></div>

<div id="secondMark"></div>

<div id="thirdMark"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";

ul li { list-style-type:none; }

/* navigation */
#navigation { position:fixed; z-index:5; bottom:80px; left:-26px; background-color:#FFF; width:70px; height:190px; border-top-right-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; }

.menubutton { float:left; width:20px; height:20px; border-radius: 50%; background-color:#F00; margin-bottom:15px; }

.menubutton:hover { cursor:pointer; }

#homeLink { background-color:#007FD2; }
#aboutLink { background-color:#C7007A; }
#musicLink { background-color:#FFDB1A; }
#brandsLink { background-color:#000; }
#contactLink { background-color:#F90; }

#homeLink:hover { background-color:#006DB4; }
#aboutLink:hover { background-color:#99005E; }
#musicLink:hover { background-color:#FFC61A; }
#brandsLink:hover { background-color:#333; }
#contactLink:hover { background-color:#F60; }


#container {
    position:absolute;
    width:10000px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFC;  
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#firstMark {
    position:absolute;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    left:3000px;    
}

#secondMark {
    position:absolute;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    left:6000px;    
}

#thirdMark {
    position:absolute;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    left:9000px;    
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#homeLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.scrollTo(0,0, {duration: 2000});
    });

    $('#aboutLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.scrollTo('#firstMark', {duration: 2000});
    });

    $('#musicLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.scrollTo('#secondMark', {duration: 2000});
    });

});
```

Here's the [link](http://kode.co.nf/scrolldemo/) to a demo page. This works in Firefox(v18), Opera(v12), Safari(v5.1.2) and even Internet Explorer 9 but it doesn't work in Chrome(v24).

Can anybody tell me what's missing here? It it something wrong with my code or a bug in the plugin?

Failing that, please tell me if there are any other alternatives to automatic scrolling which also supports horizontal scrolling.

Thank you.

Comment: Interestingly, StackOverflow uses the outdated ScrollTo in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/), meaning that every time anyone talks, the entire screen scrolls from the top.

Answer (score 4):

Old question but I'll write down my experience.
I had the same issue with that plugin downloaded from http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

That plugin in the article is outdated, you can download the latest version here: https://github.com/flesler

Also you will also have to change

`$.scrollTo(0,0, {duration: 2000});`

to

`$.scrollTo("0px","0px", {duration: 2000});`

Answer (score 2):

Your anchor might be receiving the `click` event rather than the div.

Just give this a quick try:

```
$('#homeLink a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
    $.scrollTo(0,0, {duration: 2000});
});
```

I added an `alert('click')` as well so you can tell if it's been detected.

Comment: Tried that. It did not work either. Doing this also disables scrolling in other browsers as well.

Comment: Yes, that too. No alert came up.

Comment: That would suggest there is an issue with your targetting.

Comment: But it works in other browsers. This issue occurs only in Chrome

Comment: Works for me in Chrome, I just tried it on your web page via the chrome inspector.

Comment: Really? You mean just my original code or after you modified the selector?

Comment: hmm...Maybe I should clear my cache and try it again. Thanks.

Comment: The scroll part didn't work... but the selector definitely fired the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Try using px will scroll value

Change

```
 $.scrollTo(0,0, {duration: 2000});
```

to

```
 $.scrollTo(0px,0px, {duration: 2000});
```

Comment: duration is a time element (seconds).

Comment: that's better, might require quotes now though.

Comment: @diggersworld is right. But what that line does is it scrolls to the beginning. I want the others links to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in webkit's ability to animate the body. Instead, create a div just inside body and apply the animation to this instead...

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <a class="scroll-to-id" href="#" data-target="section1">Section 1</a>
            <a class="scroll-to-id" href="#" data-target="section2">Section 2</a>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <a id="section1">&nbsp;</a>
            <p>Some content<p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <a id="section2">&nbsp;</a>
            <p>Some more content<p>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Note:** In my personal experience, the ID could be just as effectively applied to the  tag instead of a redundant  and this still work ... I've only done it this way in this example because some users noted issues with targeting IDs higher up the DOM tree than this ... I couldn't personally recreate that problem, so hey, either way works!

Then style the wrapper element and body to behave correctly

```
body { position:relative; }

.wrapper { overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:0; height:100%; width:100%; }
```

Then the jQuery

```
$('.scroll-to-id').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = "#" + $(this).data('target');
    $('.wrapper').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1500);
});
```